# Django - No apps.py when running startapp

Tags: python, django

Django version: Django-1.9.7
I am following this tutorial:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/

I get to this step:

```
python manage.py startapp polls
```

once I run it I should get a folder called polls and within it there are several files, I am missing the apps.py file.

Is there a way to generate this? Why didn't it get created?

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and I installed django via pip

Ubuntu ships with 2 versions of python, so are there two versions of django? How can I check?

EDIT: I had the packages

```
python-django-common python-django python3-django
```

installed, I removed them and did what udi suggested and it ended being 1.9.7.

Comment: When you run `python manage.py --version`, does it print `1.9.7`?

Comment: @Udi Strangely I get 1.8.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running the wrong version of Django.

Use `python manage.py --version` to check which version of Django is installed.

(If you use more then one version of Python (Python 2 + Python 3) or if you are using virtualenvs, you might have more than one version of Django installed side by side in different pythons).

Comment: For me, I forgot to use the `python3` command and was instead using `python` which refers to 2.7.

Answer (score 3):

ref : https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24971

I guess it might look like:

in apps.py add this code:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class AppnameConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'appname'
```

and in **init**.py add this code:

```
default_app_config = 'appname.apps.AppnameConfig'
```

Comment: this working, I don't have apps.py in Django==1.8.6 and adding this will help for makemigrations